# Hydration payload is incorrect after dispatching a thunk

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, next.js, next-redux-wrapper

I'm using `next-redux-wrapper`, and on my `wrapper.getServersideProps` I'm dispatching a thunk, but during hydration it's action returns a payload of same value of initial state. Why?

My Thunk:

```
export const fetchData = createAsyncThunk<IData>(
  "fetch-data",
  async () => {
    const res = await fetch(
      "https://..."
    );
    const data: Promise<IData> = res.json();
    console.log("data", data) //it's able to fetch the data;

    return data;
  }
);
```

My extraReducers:

```
builder.addCase(HYDRATE, (state, action: AnyAction) => {
       // the action.payload has the same value of initial state (not updated)
      console.log("data-action", action.payload.mySlice); 

      if (!action.payload.mySlice.data) {
        return state;
      }
      state.data = action.payload.mySlice.data;
    });

 builder
      .addCase(fetchData.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        console.log("fulfilled");

        // action.payload is correct and return fetched data from API    
        state.data = action.payload; 
        state.error = false;
        state.loading = false;
      })
```

getServerSideProps:

```
export const getServerSideProps = wrapper.getServerSideProps(
  (store) =>
    async ({ params }) => {
      await store.dispatch(fetchData());

      return {
        props: {},
      };
    }
);
```

I also tried dispatching the data inside my thunk, but didn't work either.

**Update**

Now it works but only when I dispatch data inside the thunk after, adding an `await` before store.dispatch(fetchData()).

Comment: can you show that `getServersideProps` in question?

Comment: @phry check my update.